# Using a dialog box to graphically retrieve user input

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++, dialog

I am not new in C++ but this is my first time developing a Win32 program. It has to be graphical and so I have been attempting to get user input using an input/dialog box with no success.

I have read [this topic on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and found it helpful, but I get an error about `IDD_PASSWORD` and `IDE_PASSWORD` not being defined. Declaring them in `resource.h` and giving arbitrary values (like 110, 111) yields no results. Other attempts I have tried to modify the auto-generated about box, which also yields no results after modification, I noticed that if i change the value of `IDD_ABOUTBOX` in `resource.h` from 103, this also does not work.  I also tried using the .rc under Resource View, but still no results.

So I'd like to know if the resource box templates have predefined constant numbers that i have to use, if so where because I searched that too or if there is another way to obtain user input in a windowed application. I just want to obtain an integer, that's all.

Comment: Does it have to be C++? For a first GUI endeavor I would recommend C#. It is many, many times easier.

Comment: Yes it has to be, thank you. it's sort of am assesment that i have been able to solve except i can't get the user input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing magic in the numbers assigned to resources. The numbers are what the code actually uses to identify the resources. Visual Studio just allows you to assign symbolic names to those numbers through the use of C macros (i.e., `#define`) to make your code easier to read. These values are all defined in the file `resource.h` by convention, and although you can modify that file manually, you usually should not do so—let the Visual Studio Resource Editor handle that for you.

The problem you're running into is that you actually have to *create* those resources first before the numbers will mean anything. When you create a new Win32 project, Visual Studio will automatically create an about box dialog and give it the symbolic ID `IDD_ABOUTBOX`. However, there is no such `IDD_PASSWORD` dialog created by default in a new project, and there isn't one built into Windows.

You can create this dialog yourself using the Dialog Editor (part of Visual Studio's Resource Editor), which is pretty easy to do as it allows you to drag controls around on the dialog where WYSIWYG. When you add a new dialog box to your project's resources, you will be given the option to name it anything you like. You can use `IDD_PASSWORD` if you want, or any other name. A numeric ID will be assigned automatically based on an algorithm; generally the lowest available number is used.

The article you linked to is assuming that you have already added a dialog to your project with the symbolic name `IDD_PASSWORD` (which is probably a mistake on the part of the author). All it shows you is how to display that dialog once it exists as part of your project's resources.

It's going to be somewhat difficult to learn Win32 programming just by reading the MSDN documentation. I strongly suggest getting a book that explains it more clearly and in a more logical order. The canonical text is Charles Petzold's [Programming Windows, 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X). Note that you will need to make sure you get the 5th edition, as [the newer editions digress from their Win32 roots and start talking about completely unrelated things like C# and Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/17/10306079.aspx).

If you absolutely must learn by trial-and-error and MSDN, start reading about dialog box resources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26ewt5yf.aspx).

Comment: Wow this is really helpful, thank you Cody Gray. If i'v been paying enough attention, the only time i saw a GUI designer was when i viewed the .rc files in resource view though. you have been great help.

Comment: Yup, it'll show up if you double-click on a dialog box resource in the Resource View window. Right-click on your project in Resource View to add a new dialog box (or any other resource).

Comment: Thanks, went through the book and the link you provided, useful resources...i am set to graduate soon, applied for a job then they sent me an assessment requiring a win32 code and executables, yet i have 0 experience there. Your info has been really helpful